# MvC4 using 2 submit forms on the same row

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, submit, row

So this is the code, i have 2 submit buttons when i press "Start" I want it to send the Datetime.now to the start row, and when i press "Stop" i want it to send the Stop datetime.now to the column, this should be happening in the same row. And when i press Start again it should generate a new ID 2, etc. print the start date on the second row.

Exampel ID 1 : Start 2013-11-15 05:12 Slut : 2013-11-15 05:15

Greetings Patrik

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Start)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Start, new { style = "display: none;", @Value = @DateTime.Now })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start)
        </div>
         <p>
            <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Command)" value="Start" formaction="/tider/create" />
        </p>

    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Slut)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Slut, new { @Value = @DateTime.Now })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Slut)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Command)"  value="Stop" />
        </p>
    }
</fieldset>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Slut)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Slut, new { @Value = @DateTime.Now })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Slut)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

controller 
    {
        public class TiderController : Controller
        {
            private TiderDBContext db = new TiderDBContext();

```
        //
        // GET: /Tider/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Tider.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Tider/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            ArbetsTider arbetstider = db.Tider.Find(id);
            if (arbetstider == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(arbetstider);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Tider/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Tider/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ArbetsTider arbetstider)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Tider.Add(arbetstider);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            return View(arbetstider);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Tider/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            ArbetsTider arbetstider = db.Tider.Find(id);
            if (arbetstider == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(arbetstider);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Tider/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(ArbetsTider arbetstider)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(arbetstider).State = EntityState.Modified;

               return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(arbetstider);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Tider/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            ArbetsTider arbetstider = db.Tider.Find(id);
            if (arbetstider == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(arbetstider);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Tider/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            ArbetsTider arbetstider = db.Tider.Find(id);
            db.Tider.Remove(arbetstider);
            db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Start(ArbetsTider model)
        {
            using (var context = new TiderDBContext())
            {
                context.Tider.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == model.ID).Start = model.Start;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Stop(ArbetsTider model)
        {
            using (var context = new TiderDBContext())
            {
                context.Tider.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == model.ID).Slut = model.Slut;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

model

```
public class ArbetsTider
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Slut { get; set; }

}

public class TiderDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ArbetsTider> Tider { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What did the model do to be labelled as slut?!

Comment: Haha, im from sweden.. Slut = Stop :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, HTML doesn't really deal with multiple forms very well.

You can't, for example, have nested forms:

```
<form action="/GreatController/DecentAction">
    <input type="submit" value="Start" />

    <form action="/GoodController/ModerateAction">
        <input type="submit" value="Stop" />
    </form>

</form>
```

You can't have a form that does two different things with the same data (with just HTML), even if you use two different buttons.

There are a few ways around this.

1. **Javascript** - You can use Javascript to help you in all sorts of ways. It can create a new, hidden form, create hidden fields or simply change the `action` of a form when you submit with a particular button. The possibilities are numerous.
2. **Rethink** - Ask yourself if you can achieve the same functionality but by going at it in a different way.
3. **Split the forms up** - Are you able to separate the form into two forms? Remember that the forms only need to contain the data (i.e. input fields) necessary to perform an action, they don't need to necessarily wrap large amounts of unrelated HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure i understod your answer, i ask you direct here isntead.

Using 2 submit buttons for the same row but diffrent colums is not as easy as i think?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>ArbetsTider</legend>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Start)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Start, new { style = "display: none;", @Value = @DateTime.Now })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Command)" value="Start" formaction="/tider/create" />
        </p>
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Slut)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Slut, new { @Value = @DateTime.Now })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Slut)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Command)"  value="Create" />
        </p>
    }
</fieldset>
```

Add a string property name "Command" to your model, and in your action, do one thing if  `"model.Command" == "Start"` and another if `"model.Command" == "Create"` e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MultipleCommand(string Command)


    if (model.Command == "Start")
    {
        //TO DO : Submit button for first row
    }
    else if (model.Command == "Stop");
    {
        //TO DO : Submit to second row
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Joking aside:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Start"))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Start)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Start, new { style = "display: none;", @Value = @DateTime.Now })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start)
        </div>
         <p>
            <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Command)" value="Start" formaction="/tider/create" />
        </p>

    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Stop"))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Slut)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Slut, new { @Value = @DateTime.Now })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Slut)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Command)"  value="Stop" />
        </p>
    }
```

And in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Start(IDontKnowYourModel model){
 using(var context = new TiderDBContext()) {
   context.Tider.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == model.ID).Start = model.Start;
   context.SaveChanges();
 }
 return View("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Stop(IDontKnowYourModel model){
 using(var context = new TiderDBContext()) {
   context.Tider.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == model.ID).Slut = model.Slut;
   context.SaveChanges();
 }
 return View("Index");
}
```

Note: normally you add an extra DAL layer inbetween, like a repository. I haven't done this to keep things concise.

All you should have to do is define in the form what action method it should point to.
Your question is somewhat unclear (What do you mean with "on the same row?"), so depending on your usecase you might have to add a hidden field to each form to determine the ID of the model you're trying to update.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to make it some what clear to you now then :)

I have the 3 diffrent columns ID,Start,Stop. 

When i press "Start"-submit button, i want it to send the Start-date to the start-column and when i press "Stop"-submit button i want it to send the Stop-date to the stop-column.

I added the model also in the update.

Comment: @PatrikChristoffersson: see my edit, that should be about it.

Comment: How should the controller look really?